# If c = A · E, then A - cE = 0.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ be any unit vector, that is a vector of norm $1$. Let $c$ be the component
of $A$ along $E$. $c = A·E$.

Is it possible to show that If $c = A · E$, then $A - cE · E = 0$?

Comment: Don't know about that edit... $E\cdot E=1$...

Comment: Before the edit, the result was correct: not now.

Comment: A - cE is perpendicular to E.

Answer (score 0):

You want to see that $A-cE = 0$.

Multiply both sides by $E$, and you get:

$$0 \cdot E = 0 = (A-cE) E = AE - cE^2 = AE - c \| E \| ^2$$

Since $E$ has norm $1$:

$$0 = AE - c = c-c = 0$$